# CAST (CASE WHEN Id IS IN ( SELECT RefId FROM RefTable WHERE RefId =someId)THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Hi i have a problem with my procedure

**Stored-Procedure:**

```
SELECT dbo.Table1.*,
       CAST (CASE WHEN Table1.Id IS IN ( SELECT Id 
                                         FROM dbo.Table2 
                                         WHERE RefRolleId =@Id) 
              THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit) AS selected
FROM   dbo.Table1
```

**ERROR:**
wrong syntax near to IN-Keyword
wrong syntax near to THEN-Keyword

i googled around but i doesn't found an example for an Case with an IN operator
could somebody please enlight me whats wrong

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove `IS` and it will work (*this is just to answer your question directly and nothing else (eg performance improvement)*)

```
SELECT dbo.Table1.*,
       CAST (CASE WHEN Table1.Id  IN ( SELECT Id 
                                         FROM dbo.Table2 
                                         WHERE RefRolleId =@Id) 
              THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS bit) AS selected
FROM   dbo.Table1
```

Answer (score 2):

@JW is correct, but I would suggest changing your query, something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.*,
       CAST (CASE 
                WHEN T2.Id IS NOT NULL
                THEN 0 
                ELSE 1 
             END AS bit) AS selected
FROM   dbo.Table1 T
   LEFT JOIN dbo.Table2 T2 ON T.Id = T2.Id AND T2.RefRolleId =@Id
```

I think this might yield a better performance.

Good luck.